# azure-documentdb: Need help : Client creation fails with Json Exception

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb

Tried with two versions of 'azure-documentdb' library : 2.4.7 and 2.3.0 . Same error.

When I am trying to create a client object of type DocumentClient , I receive following error:

> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found for the initial request to read information
>   from the Cosmos-Db.

Code used is as simple as:

```
docClient = new DocumentClient("https://xxx.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:443/", "<primary-key>", null /* Providing a policy also did made no difference */ , ConsistencyLevel.Session);
```

Exception received is as follows:

```
01:22:16.635 [main] INFO com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient - Initializing DocumentClient with serviceEndpoint [https://xxx.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:443/], ConnectionPolicy [ConnectionPolicy [requestTimeout=10, directRequestTimeout10, mediaRequestTimeout=300, connectionMode=DirectHttps, mediaReadMode=Buffered, maxPoolSize=800, idleConnectionTimeout=60, userAgentSuffix=, retryOptions=com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.RetryOptions@20398b7c, enableEndpointDiscovery=true, preferredLocations=null, usingMultipleWriteLocations=false, handleServiceUnavailableFromProxy=false]], ConsistencyLevel [Session]
01:22:17.159 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
01:22:17.159 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://xxx.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 800; total allocated: 0 of 800]
01:22:17.168 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://xxx.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 800; total allocated: 1 of 800]
01:22:17.169 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Opening connection {s}->https://xxx.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:443
01:22:17.332 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to xxx.mongo.cosmos.azure.com/xx.xx.xx.xx:443
01:22:17.332 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Connecting socket to xxx.mongo.cosmos.azure.com/xx.xx.xx.xx:443 with timeout 10000
01:22:17.639 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
01:22:17.639 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
01:22:17.639 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Starting handshake
01:22:18.237 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Secure session established
01:22:18.237 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
01:22:18.237 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
01:22:18.238 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer principal: CN=*.table.cosmosdb.azure.com
01:22:18.238 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer alternative names: [*.gremlin.cosmosdb.azure.com, *.cassandra.cosmosdb.azure.com, *.table.cosmosdb.azure.com, *.sql.cosmosdb.azure.com, *.etcd.cosmosdb.azure.com, *.gremlin.cosmos.azure.com, *.mongo.cosmos.azure.com, *.cassandra.cosmos.azure.com, *.table.cosmos.azure.com, *.sql.cosmos.azure.com, *.etcd.cosmos.azure.com, *.documents.azure.com]
01:22:18.238 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  issuer principal: CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 2, OU=Microsoft IT, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, ST=Washington, C=US
01:22:18.242 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established 192.168.1.7:62386<->40.83.137.191:443
01:22:18.242 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 10000
01:22:18.242 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Executing request GET / HTTP/1.1
01:22:18.242 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
01:22:18.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> GET / HTTP/1.1
01:22:18.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> x-ms-version: 2018-09-17
01:22:18.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Cache-Control: no-cache
01:22:18.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Windows10/10.0 JRE/1.8.0_241 documentdb-java-sdk/2.3.0
01:22:18.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> x-ms-consistency-level: Session
01:22:18.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> authorization: type%3Dmaster%26ver%3D1.0%26sig%3Drm2cvkJRHj%2FNTcBOcjOHaYUKIKg3%2BqULmOUn9PD3z8Y%3D
01:22:18.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept: application/json
01:22:18.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> x-ms-date: Sun, 26 Apr 2020 19:52:17 GMT
01:22:18.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: xxxx.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:443
01:22:18.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
01:22:18.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
01:22:18.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "GET / HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
01:22:18.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "x-ms-version: 2018-09-17[\r][\n]"
01:22:18.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
01:22:18.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Windows10/10.0 JRE/1.8.0_241 documentdb-java-sdk/2.3.0[\r][\n]"
01:22:18.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "x-ms-consistency-level: Session[\r][\n]"
01:22:18.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "authorization: type%3Dmaster%26ver%3D1.0%26sig%3Drm2cvkJRHj%2FNTcBOcjOHaYUKIKg3%2BqULmOUn9PD3z8Y%3D[\r][\n]"
01:22:18.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
01:22:18.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "x-ms-date: Sun, 26 Apr 2020 19:52:17 GMT[\r][\n]"
01:22:18.245 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: xxx.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:443[\r][\n]"
01:22:18.245 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
01:22:18.245 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
01:22:18.245 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
01:22:18.500 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found[\r][\n]"
01:22:18.500 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
01:22:18.501 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0[\r][\n]"
01:22:18.501 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Sun, 26 Apr 2020 19:52:18 GMT[\r][\n]"
01:22:18.501 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
01:22:18.501 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "0[\r][\n]"
01:22:18.501 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
01:22:18.507 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
01:22:18.507 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
01:22:18.507 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
01:22:18.507 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Sun, 26 Apr 2020 19:52:18 GMT
01:22:18.519 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
01:22:18.525 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection [id: 0][route: {s}->https://xxx.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:443] can be kept alive indefinitely
01:22:18.525 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://xxx.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 800; total allocated: 1 of 800]
01:22:18.532 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Cancelling request execution
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON String: ''
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.JsonSerializable.<init>(JsonSerializable.java:76)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.Resource.<init>(Resource.java:43)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.Error.<init>(Error.java:22)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.internal.ErrorUtils.maybeThrowException(ErrorUtils.java:60)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.internal.GatewayProxy.performGetRequest(GatewayProxy.java:242)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.internal.GatewayProxy.doRead(GatewayProxy.java:93)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient.getDatabaseAccountFromEndpointPrivate(DocumentClient.java:3163)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient.getDatabaseAccountFromEndpoint(DocumentClient.java:3151)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.GlobalEndpointManager$1.getDatabaseAccountFromEndpoint(GlobalEndpointManager.java:55)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.GlobalEndpointManager.getDatabaseAccountFromAnyEndpoint(GlobalEndpointManager.java:121)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.internal.BaseDatabaseAccountConfigurationProvider.<init>(BaseDatabaseAccountConfigurationProvider.java:22)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient.createBaseDatabaseAccountConfigurationProvider(DocumentClient.java:377)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient.initialize(DocumentClient.java:336)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient.<init>(DocumentClient.java:234)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient.<init>(DocumentClient.java:132)
    at com.eysamples.serverless.ss.service.CosmoDbClient.<init>(CosmoDbClient.java:23)
    at com.eysamples.serverless.ss.service.CosmoDbClient.main(CosmoDbClient.java:38)
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:194)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:321)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.JsonSerializable.<init>(JsonSerializable.java:74)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: From your code snippet, it appears you created a MongoDB API instance. Is that correct? If so, you can't use `DocumentClient`, as that class is specific to the SQL API. For the MongoDB API, you'd use the native MongoDB SDK for your language of choice.

Comment: According to your code, you want to connect  MongoDB with sdk `azure-documentdb`.  It is wrong. It just can be used to connect Azure Cosmos DB SQL API(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-java). If you want to connect Azure Cosmos MongoDB API, you can use MongoDB Java driver. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-mongodb-java and https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/java

Comment: @DavidMakogon : Thanks for the update David. It looks like I am mistaken in my approach.

Comment: @Ankzz Never mind,maybe you could summarize the experience as an answer for your own note.That will be great!